# Issue while mocking function called through another function

Tags: c++, c++17, googletest, googlemock

I am getting mad trying to make the code below working.

```cpp
#include <string>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class Base {

public:
  Base() = default;
  virtual ~Base() = default;

  template<typename T>
  bool get_bool(const std::string& value) {
    return false;
  }

};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived<T>() = default;
  virtual ~Derived<T>() = default;

  bool do_job(const std::string& value) {
    return get_bool<T>(value);
  }
};


template<typename T>
class MockDerived: public Derived<T> {

public:
  MockDerived() = default;
  ~MockDerived() = default;

  bool get_bool(const std::string& value) {
    return Base::get_bool<T>(value);
  }

  MOCK_METHOD1(my_get_bool, bool(const std::string& name));
};

template<>
bool MockDerived<int>::get_bool(const std::string& value) {
  return my_get_bool(value);
}

template<>
bool MockDerived<double>::get_bool(const std::string& value) {
  return my_get_bool(value);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

TEST(my_test, get_bool_int) {
  MockDerived<int> d;

  EXPECT_CALL(d, my_get_bool(testing::_))
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(testing::Return(true));

  ASSERT_TRUE(d.do_job("65537"));
}

TEST(my_test, get_bool_double) {
  MockDerived<double> d;

  EXPECT_CALL(d, my_get_bool(testing::_))
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(testing::Return(true));

  ASSERT_TRUE(d.do_job("65537"));
}

TEST(my_test, get_bool_float) {
  MockDerived<float> d;

  ASSERT_FALSE(d.do_job("65537"));
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The design is very similar to my code. I just simplify it a lot to give you a short example illustrating my issue.
When I am running this code, I just want to get `true` for `int` and `double` type.
How can I get to it please?

I am using c++17 with gtest/gmock 1.11.0.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: get_bool is not virtual. Why do you expect Derived::do_job calls MockDerived::get_bool?

Comment: Unrelated: since you are using 1.11 you can stop using old abomination `MOCK_METHOD1` and start using unified `MOCK_METHOD(bool, my_get_bool, (const std::string&))` macros.

Comment: @273 : get_bool cannot be virtual because it is a templated method like specializing the template method…So I try many many things before asking help here.. I repeat that I simplifie the code a lot. What I am trying to do is to unitary test the do_job method using a mock for get_bool because it takes to much effort to instantiate Base class. So I post here my last try…

Comment: @ixSci ok! Thanks for the tip.. I was using the 1.6.x version before.. i just upgrade to the last version a few days ago

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2660). The problem is that mocking relies on dynamic polymorphism and any code that doesn't follow that rule will be hard (and ugly) to mock. Making code testable/mockable is a design principle/tradeoff.